# What is the difference between MEDIUMTEXT and MEDIUMBLOB in MariaDB?

Tags: text, mariadb, blob, mediawiki

I've just seen that MediaWiki uses `MEDIUMBLOB` for `text.old_text`. Looking at the documentation, [`MEDIUMBLOB`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mediumblob/) and [`MEDIUMTEXT`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mediumtext/) look almost identical:

> A BLOB column with a maximum length of 16,777,215 (2^24 - 1) bytes. Each MEDIUMBLOB value is stored using a three-byte length prefix that indicates the number of bytes in the value.

and

> A TEXT column with a maximum length of 16,777,215 (2^24 - 1) characters. The effective maximum length is less if the value contains multi-byte characters. Each MEDIUMTEXT value is stored using a three-byte length prefix that indicates the number of bytes in the value.

My guess is that BLOB columns behave differently for sorting, but besides that they behave exactly the same.

So the question is: Why does MediaWiki then use BLOB instead of text? Is there any other difference, e.g. for backups?

Answer (score 1):

A `BLOB` column (tiny, medium, long) contains the bytes provided.

A `TEXT` column does that too, but it has a `CHARACTER SET`, so it can convert and/or check the characters for validity during `INSERT`.

If the encoding in the client is different than declared for the column in the table, the encoding is converted.  See `SET NAMES`.  Typical encodings are `latin1` and `utf8mb4`.

Upon reading (`SELECT`) the reverse trans-coding is performed.

But if the client has, say, latin1 bytes, and the connection incorrectly claims that the client is encoded utf8mb4 (UTF-8), then any of several nasties happen -- Mojibake (gibberish), truncation, question marks, etc.

I suspect that `old_text` was declared to be `MEDIUMBLOB` to avoid the character set issues.  This has the downside of not knowing how to display the old_text.

Sorting and comparing (such as with `=`) also differs.  `BLOB` just looks at the bits.  `TEXT` may do case folding, regional-specific equivalences, etc., depending on the chosen `COLLATION`.

Comment: `utf8mb4` was introduced in 2010, before that blobs and varbinary were the only sane way to store Unicode text. MediaWiki development is largely driven by Wikipedia, and the Wikipedia database is huge and schema changes take forever, and binary text already works, so there is little incentive to mess with it. Also, it is easier to support other DB engines this way which don't always have the same encoding/decoding behavior.

Comment: @Tgr - Your Comment is a better Answer than mine, in that it explains the motivation in Wiki.  Suggest you write an Answer.